# Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: Docker Installation on Windows-10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting below error while starting/installing the **Docker** on **windows-10**. I am following this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymlWt1MqURY&t=305s

**Error**:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\pc\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\pc\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to create a network adapter. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a network adapter. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V. (VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:03.537940 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: In my post also I mentioned it as Windows-10 machine

Comment: Yes, I should have seen that. I was actually thinking about edition (pro, home, etc...), but you probably have pro. [This looks a little outdated](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3204980/virtualization-applications-do-not-work-together-with-hyper-v-device-g), but something you can try.